Azure Application Insights Logs Query Returning Incorrect Values(Zero) for Metrics
When I executed azure application insights logs query from azure logic apps "Run query and visualize results" showing the results as zero for all the metrics in the query. But when I execute the same query directly from azure application insights logs it is showing the correct values.
When I execute my below query in application insights logs
let TotalUsersCurrentWeek = toscalar(
    requests
    | where timestamp >= ago(7d)
    | where name == "Login request"
    | summarize TotalUsersCurrentWeek=dcount(user_Id)
);

let TotalUsersPreviousWeek = toscalar(
    requests
    | where timestamp >= ago(14d) and timestamp < ago(7d)
    | where name == "Login request"
    | summarize TotalUsersPreviousWeek=dcount(user_Id)
);

let FailedLoginsCurrentWeek = toscalar(
    requests
    | where timestamp >= ago(7d)
    | where name == "Failed login request"
    | summarize FailedLoginsCurrentWeek=count()
);

let FailedLoginsPreviousWeek = toscalar(
    requests
    | where timestamp >= ago(14d) and timestamp < ago(7d)
    | where name == "Failed login request"
    | summarize FailedLoginsPreviousWeek=count()
);

let AvgLoginTimeCurrentWeek = toscalar(
    requests
    | where timestamp >= ago(7d)
    | where name == "Login request"
    | summarize AvgLoginTimeCurrentWeek=avg(duration)
);

let AvgLoginTimePreviousWeek = toscalar(
    requests
    | where timestamp >= ago(14d) and timestamp < ago(7d)
    | where name == "Login request"
    | summarize AvgLoginTimePreviousWeek=avg(duration)
);

print 
    TotalUsersCurrentWeek, 
    TotalUsersPreviousWeek, 
    FailedLoginsCurrentWeek, 
    FailedLoginsPreviousWeek, 
    AvgLoginTimeCurrentWeek, 
    AvgLoginTimePreviousWeek
| project 
    TotalUsersCurrentWeek = TotalUsersCurrentWeek,
    TotalUsersPreviousWeek = TotalUsersPreviousWeek,
    FailedLoginsCurrentWeek = FailedLoginsCurrentWeek,
    FailedLoginsPreviousWeek = FailedLoginsPreviousWeek,
    AvgLoginTimeCurrentWeek = AvgLoginTimeCurrentWeek,
    AvgLoginTimePreviousWeek = AvgLoginTimePreviousWeek

results are showing correctly
screenshot from application insights logs query
When I run the same query from Azure Logic Apps > "Run query and visualize results" > "Send an email(v2)" all the values are showing as zero.
screenshot from email report
I verified the service connection from logic apps to correct application insights resource.
Is there any way to fix this issue?

I have reproduced in my environment and I do not see any issues in design:
The only observation i can make is the Time Range In Logic app:

Design which worked for me :
My kql query:
let x = toscalar(
    traces
    | summarize operation_Name=dcount(operation_Name)
);
let y = toscalar(
    traces
    | summarize client_City=count()
);
print 
    x,
    y
| project 
operation_Name_Count=x,
client_City_Count=y


Then:

When I run in Application Insights:

Logic App Output:

Make sure you set the right resource and query. If still you face this issue, I would suggest you to raise support request as there is no design issue here.

thank you @RithwikBojja for checking this, it was a miss from my end, i find out that i used the incorrect application insights resource name in logic apps that's why it returned zero results.
